# jQuery's isFunction and InternetExplorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

When adapting jQuery's isFunction method

```
isFunction: function( obj ) {
  return toString.call(obj) === "[object Function]";
}
```

InternetExlorer 8 returns the following error: "Object doesn't support this property or method". [A good article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/how-ie9-platform-preview-feedback-changed-the-javascript-standard) digging into this function won't fix this behaviour. To check wether *obj* is defined, I changed the function in reference [to the MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/how-ie9-platform-preview-feedback-changed-the-javascript-standard):

```
isFunction: function( obj ) {
  return obj && toString.call(obj) === "[object Function]";
}
```

Any other ideas for a solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call the `toString` method directly from the `Object.prototype` object:

```
function isFunction (obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Function]";
}

alert(isFunction({})); // false
alert(isFunction(function{})); // true
```

jQuery has a local variable named `toString` that refers to the method on `Object.prototype`.

Calling just `toString.call(obj);` without declaring a `toString` identifier on scope, works on Firefox, Chrome, etc, just because the Global object inherits from `Object.prototype`, but this is not guaranteed by the spec.

```
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(window); // false on IE
```

The article you link to talks about a change that was introduced in the ECMAScript 5th Edition specification to the `call` and `apply` methods.

Those methods allow you to invoke a function passing the first argument as the `this` value of the invoked function.

On ECMAScript 3, if this argument was `undefined` or `null`, the `this` value of the invoked function will refer to the global object, for example:

```
function test () {  return this; }
test.call(null) === window; // true
```

But that changed in ES5, the value should now be passed without modification and that caused the `Object.prototype.toString` to throw an exception, because an object argument was expected.

The specification of that method changed, now if the `this` value refers to `undefined` or `null` the string `"[object Undefined]"` or `"[object Null]"` will be returned, fixing the problem (thing that I don't think is really good, since both results results feel just wrong, `undefined` and `null` are *not* objects, they are primitives... that made me remember `typeof null == 'object'`... Moreover I think it messes up with the concept of the `[[Class]]` internal property, anyway...)

Now you might wonder why jQuery uses this method to check for a function object, instead of using the `typeof` operator?

Implementation bugs, for example in Chrome/Safari/WebKit, the `typeof` for RegExp objects returns `"function"`, because RegExp objects where made *callable*, e.g.:

```
typeof /foo/; // "function" in Chrome/Safari/WebKit
```

The `typeof` operator returns `"function"` if the object implements the `[[Call]]` internal property, which made objects to be *callable*.

This was originally introduced by the Mozilla implementations, invoking a RegExp object is equivalent to call the `exec` method.

Answer (score 1):

What purpose is the `isFunction` function trying to serve? Is it intended to deal with host objects (i.e. DOM nodes, `window` etc. in browsers), or regular expressions (which as CMS points out in the comments are callable and return "function" with `typeof` in some browsers)? If not, all you need is

```
typeof obj == "function"
```

If it is supposed to deal with host methods, then it's flawed because there's no obligation that the browser must return "[object Function]" for host methods. In IE there are many callable host properties that won't return "[object Function]" or will throw an error. For example:

```
alert(Object.prototype.toString.call(document.createElement));
```

... gives "[object Object]" in IE.

Comment: A problem, not involved with host objects exist on Chrome/Safari/Webkit, where RegExp objects are reported as `"function"` by the `typeof` operator, because they were made *callable*, thing that is not part of the ECMAScript Standard, they implement `[[Call]]` internally...

Comment: Yes. I'd forgotten about that until you mentioned it. Good point.

Answer (score -1):

I just ran this in IE 8's console:

```
>>$.isFunction(undefined);
false
```

Works fine.

The blog post you reference concerns IE **9**.